# NullReferenceException was unhandled on button_click [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, runtime-error, unhandled-exception

I have a problem with my code. During debug mode, there is no error or warning at all. But when i pressed a button, an error comes up. This is my code:

```
Private Sub Button11_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 10


        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", (TextBox1.Text))
        WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("saveBtn").InvokeMember("click")

   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login") will return "NOTHING" if the element is not found. You should inspect this first to make sure it is NOT NOTHING before calling other methods on it.

Comment: RE: debug - check your Debug, Options and Settings... Uncheck My Code and Break when exceptions cross domains... to see more errors in debug.

Answer (score 0):

You should, as Steve said in the comments, use some kind of Error handling to your code...i.e try....catch method to make sure that everything is valid in the WebBrowser. Try something like this

```
Private Sub Button11_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button11.Click
    Button1.Enabled = True
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 10
        Try
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login").SetAttribute("value", (TextBox1.Text))
            WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("saveBtn").InvokeMember("click")
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    Next i
End Sub
```

Try...Catch blocks are just methods to detect problems. In your case, lets say only few of the command inside the loop returned NULL...By using this method, you can "ignore" these problems and move on to the next "i" without throwing an exeption or dealing with wrong texts etc.